# mongodb upsert with conditional field update

Tags: mongodb

I have a script that populates a mongo db from daily server log files.  Log files come from a number of servers so the chronological order of the data is not guaranteed.  To make this simple, let's say that the document schema is this:

```
{
   _id: <username>,
   first_seen: <date>,
   last_seen: <date>,
   most_recent_ip: <string>
}
```

that is, documents are indexed by the name of the user who accessed the server.  For each user, we keep track of the first time the user was seen and the ip from the last visit.

Right now I handle this very inefficiently: first try an insert.  If it fails, retrieve a record by `_id`, then calculate updated values (e.g. `first_seen` and `most_recent_up`), and finally update the record.  This is 3 db calls per log entry, which makes the script's running time prohibitively long given the very high volume of data.

I'm wondering if I can replace this with an upsert instead.  I can see how to handle `first/last_seen`: probably something like `{$min: {'first_seen': <log_entry_date>}}` (hope this works correctly when inserting a new doc).  But how do I set `most_recent_ip` to the new value only when `<log_entry_date> > $last_seen`.

Is there generally a preferred pattern for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$set` to set the most_recent_ip, e.g.

```
db.logs.update(
    {_id:"user1"},
    {$set:{most_recent_ip:"2.2.2.2"}, $min:{first_seen:new Date()}, $max:{last_seen:new Date()}},
    {upsert: true}
)
```

Comment: I know I can just set it, but it needs to be the most recently visited, not the most recently processed (i.e. as I explained in the question, the processing order isn't guaranteed to be the chronological order).